# What is "˥˩" in the IPA?

Tags: phonetics, ipa, tone, phones

While reading the Wikipedia page on voiced bilabial trill, I came across a transcription in the [occurrence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_trill#Occurrence) section which looks like:

> [tʙ̩˥˩]

The word is from Lizu language and means 'bean'. What is bothering me is the last V-shaped letter that I can't find. It seems to be two characters, but when I search them, Google gives nothing helpful. How is this supposed to be pronounced? What sound(s) is this?

Comment: Have you tried searching Wikipedia this way: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/˥˩](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/˥˩) ? Wiki has articles on practically every symbol used in Unicode.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not a sound, but a [contour tone letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tone_letter) applying to the whole word (or syllable).  This case specifically is a high falling tone, like the fourth tone in Mandarin.

The Pumi example from the same table has another example: [pʙ̩˥], a word with a high register tone.

Comment: Oh... I was really confused because I searched different IPA charts and guides but couldn't find a trace of it.  Thank you so much!

Comment: On the [official IPA chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#/media/File:IPA_chart_2020.svg), they can be found in the lower right-hand corner in a small section called "Tones and Word Accents", labeled as "extra high" and "extra low".